# Corona: Can't drop table from database

Tags: database, sqlite, coronasdk

I have this block of code:

```
local path = system.pathForFile("data.db", system.DocumentsDirectory)
db = sqlite3.open( path )

local tablesetup = [[DROP TABLE score_floors;]]
db:exec( tablesetup )

for row2 in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM score_floors") do
   print("---->ID: " .. row2.id )
end
```

And output shows data from 'dropped table'

Can anyone help me please? Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the solution:

The name of table can't have '_' character

Comment: Have multiple tables with underscore. Only one raises error on delete or rename.